# Rename and add to $PATH

Tags: environment-variables, path, golang

I know that I can add a path to the $PATH  on the bash terminal with the command `PATH=$PATH:foo` .
I also know I can create an alias for the bash with the command `alias a=b`
But only know I noticed that an alias for the bash is not a global alias and some tools might be unable to find (which is very reasonable ,if the documentation says that the tools just search the path for another dependency).

So how can I add something to the path with a different name so that every other command line tool will find it easily ? I can think of at least three uses for my question [g++9 as default (this can be solved with update alternatives), python 3 as default and not 2] but my main question occurred when I tried to install [bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk) as bazel  because `tensorflow` build by source configurations need `bazel` , for your info I installed `bazel` with `go` in the default directory , which is `~/go/bin/bazelisk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that in two steps:

1. Make sure that your path starts with a directory in which you want to provide the "alias" names. For example, we could use the `bin/` directory in our `$HOME` directory:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

2. Put the alias names into that directory as *symbolic links*. For example, to create an alias name `python` to `python3`, run

```
ln -s $(which python3) $HOME/bin/python
```

Notes:

- You do not need to be `root` to do this.
- Be careful when you do this. Doing "weird" things like `ln -s /bin/cat $HOME/bin/ls` will backfire as much as talking to your neighbor and calling a car a fish.
- Your "alias" directory doesn't need a special name. We're not inventing a new concept here, we're just directly using how `$PATH` works.
- It will not work if your "alias" directory is last in `$PATH`, it must be first.
- Do not replace `which` with `command -v`. `command -v` will misbehave: It will print aliases, print shell-builtin commands without path, and in such situations, where a symbolic link could not be created, it would succeed giving wrong results, whereas `which` would reliably return an empty string plus set the exit status to `1`, allowing a shell script to behave properly using `if alias=$(which python3) ; then ln -s $alias ~/bin/python ; fi`. Or alternatively just fail by using `set -e; alias=$(which python3); ln -s $alias ~/bin/python`. Using `command -v` will give wrong results in case of aliases and shell-builtin commands.

Comment: The suggested edit to replace `which` with `command -v` is harmful in shell scripts. In shell scripts, `errexit` should be set. In case of an alias, `command -v` would succeed, printing `alias l='ls -CF'` for example, and the `ln` would do garbage. In case of an alias, `which` fails, stopping the script if `errexit` is set.

Comment: Another reason can be seen by `command -v echo` ⇒ `echo` vs `which echo` ⇒ `/usr/bin/echo`. In case of shell built-in commands, `command` will give the wrong result that will make the symbolic link fail.